# Loading google maps markers faster dynamically

Tags: java, sql, google-maps, coldfusion, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to generate a Google Map based off of results from a database. I can get the addresses geocoded and put out on the map, but I'm not able to do it very quickly. I have a setTimeout function to help with loading the markers; if i do not include it then not all of the markers will load.

Is there any way for me to push out the markers quickly? The markers will also eventually have InfoWindows on them as well. Note: I am using ColdFusion and SQL. [Here is what happens.](http://www.prosperityeasterniowa.org/bsc/new/testmap.cfm) Here is my code so far:

```
    <body onLoad="initialize()">

   <div id="map_canvas" class="grid_12">
   </div>

</div> 
<!end .container_12> 

</body>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function initialize(){
    // Prepare the array from ColdFusion and database
    var locations = [ 
    <cfset locationArray=ArrayNew(1)>
        <cfloop query="GetLocations">
            <cfscript>
                ArrayAppend(locationArray, #Client_Address# & ' ' & #Client_City# & ' ' & #Client_State# & ' ' & #Client_Company#);
            </cfscript>
            '<cfoutput>#Client_Address# #Client_City# #Client_State#</cfoutput>',
        </cfloop>

    ];

    //Set options of the google map
    var mapOpt = { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.48019996901214, -90.670166015625),
       zoom: 8
    };

    //Create new map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOpt);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var index = 0;

    //Begin geocoding function converting addresses to LatLng
    var geocoderFunction = function () { 
       geocoder.geocode({ 'address': locations[index] }, function (results, status) {

          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

             new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: ''
             }); 

          }

        // Call the geocoder with a 150ms delay
          index++;
          if (locations.length > index) {
             setTimeout(geocoderFunction, 150);

          }

       });

    }

    // Launch the geocoding process
    geocoderFunction();

}
</script> 
</html>
```

I'm fairly new at this, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: here is how i did it: http://anglerweb.com/fishingreports/Create
this page is used to add a fishing report to a fishing spot. basically, you will need to find a fishing spot and click on it to select. as you navigate through the map it displays fishing spots as markers after a delay. but it does show all markers fast.

Comment: When loading the page, the parent document loads quickly.  The map takes a second, then the markers pop up.  However, by the time the parent document has loaded and the map loading starts, CF has finished it's job.  The slow part is what is executing *after* the parent loads.  @LarsH pointed out what would probably be my first step in trying to optimize this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geocoding is probably the slow part. Can you do the geocoding ahead of time, store lat & long in the database, and then at mapping time just push the markers to the map with lat & long?